# Flask and SubdomainDispatcher, how the application is run at first?

Tags: flask, subdomain

I'm building a website using Flask, and I'd like to use the indicated [SubdomainDispatcher](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/appdispatch/), but I don't know how to make it work (it's missing the initial `run` to start the server).

Here's the code :

**The create_app function given [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/20/) :**

```
def create_app(database_uri, debug=False):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.debug = debug

    # set up your database
    app.engine = create_engine(database_uri)

    # add your modules
    app.register_module(frontend)

    # other setup tasks

    return app
```

**The SubdomainDispatcher :**

```
class SubdomainDispatcher(object):

    def __init__(self, domain, create_app):
        self.domain = domain
        self.create_app = create_app
        self.lock = Lock()
        self.instances = {}

    def get_application(self, host):
        host = host.split(':')[0]
        assert host.endswith(self.domain), 'Configuration error'
        subdomain = host[:-len(self.domain)].rstrip('.')
        with self.lock:
            app = self.instances.get(subdomain)
            if app is None:
                app = self.create_app(subdomain)
                self.instances[subdomain] = app
            return app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        app = self.get_application(environ['HTTP_HOST'])
        return app(environ, start_response)
```

**The main app :**

```
def make_app(subdomain):
    user = get_user_for_subdomain(subdomain)
    if user is None:
        # if there is no user for that subdomain we still have
        # to return a WSGI application that handles that request.
        # We can then just return the NotFound() exception as
        # application which will render a default 404 page.
        # You might also redirect the user to the main page then
        return NotFound()

    # otherwise create the application for the specific user
    return create_app(user)

application = SubdomainDispatcher('example.com', make_app)
```

So far, my code works without errors, but then, it stops. This is normal because no where, there is the :

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = create_app(config.DATABASE_URI, debug=True)
    application.run()
```

code that make the initial server to be run.

I tried this :

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = SubdomainDispatcher('example.com', make_app)
    application.run()
```

But it fails with :

> AttributeError: 'SubdomainDispatcher' object has no attribute 'run'

How can I run it using the SubdomainDispatcher ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's analyze your code.

You create a `SubdomainDispatcher` class that creates a `Flask` `application` and return it based on the `host` passed in `get_application`

This is also a `callable`.

The problem is that the `.run` method is of the `Flask` object (the application itself).
It is used to only `test` the application during development and it works for the single application.

So you can't test it with the development server as a whole system. You can test only one of the domains (app) at a time.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = SubdomainDispatcher('example.com', make_app)
    app = application.get_application('example.com')
    app.run()
```

The test server **is not** a full featured server.

### Better Solution

BTW I think that if you explain what you're trying to achieve (and not how you plan to do it in flask :) ) we could find a better solution. i.e. using the Flask subdomain keyword, or using a `@before_request` that localize the app parameters based on something. 
If the problem is only loading a user class based on the subdomain, there's no need of different Flask Apps (in particural cause you're using the same codebase) but you only need one `@before_request` handler.

Comment: It was a typo error, If I call `application.run()`, I have the error "AttributeError: 'SubdomainDispatcher' object has no attribute 'run'"

Comment: To be more precise, my Flask application loads an entry in the database for each subdomain (table User). I started with `@before_request` but I think this isn't application independant and could cause problems later. With this dispatcher, I'm sure that every subdomain have one and only one instance of User, which is the correct one.

Comment: By the way, do you know if it's possible, in the `make_app` function, to redirect the user ?

Comment: On `@before_request` you think wrong :) . You're in control of the user loading and you load it before each request so you can assure the correctness of the loaded class. In your approach you're trying to keep two instances of your application live without technical reason, only rising complexity in debugging.

Comment: For redirection, no. Not in that approach because you try to log a user before creating the `app` to serve the content. In your approach you need to create another `app` (ugh) to only redirect. Using `@before_request` you have the `request` proxy and all the flask suite running so you can `redirect` users in the usual way. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36096/discussion-between-cyril-n-and-paolo-casciello)

Answer (score 1):

To use `SubdomainDispatcher` with a Flask local development server, I copied most of the code from `flask.Flask.run` into a separate function and hooked in the `SubdomainDispatcher` middleware there. The heavy lifting is done by `werkzeug.serving.run_simple`:

```
def rundevserver(host=None, port=None, domain='', debug=True, **options):
    from werkzeug.serving import run_simple

    if host is None:
        host = '127.0.0.1'
    if port is None:
        port = 5000
    options.setdefault('use_reloader', debug)
    options.setdefault('use_debugger', debug)

    app = SubdomainDispatcher(create_app, domain, debug=debug)

    run_simple(host, port, app, **options)
```

For more details see my blog post: [Subdomain-based configuration for a Flask local development server](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2014/02/subdomain-based-configuration-flask-local-development-server/)